# Get google nearby places and save on sql server database

Tags: java, c#, android, web-services, android-studio

Im dealing with an application in Android Studio, and i need to get some places from Google Maps, and save them on Database. Is that possible?
Btw, if i get the places from Google, i also need to split into fields like, category, Name ,description ,etc...
Next, i will pass the fields with webservices:

```
try {
                    url = "/mobile_reg_google_places?name=" + var_name + "&category=" +var_category + "&description=" + var_description;
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    url = "/mobile_reg_google_places?name=" + var_name + "&category=" +var_category + "&description=" + var_description;
                }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible but it might be violating the [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/). `Customer will not extract, export, scrape, or cache Google Maps Content for use outside the Services` \[...\] `Caching is permitted for certain Services as described in the Maps Service Specific Terms.`

Comment: and if I just show the places, without registering in the database

Comment: It should be OK, but you should read the Terms Of Service by yourself and make sure about your specific use case.

Comment: If you want more specific help you should expand your question and show what you have already tried and what exactly is the issue. I am also confused by the tag "C#" for an Android-Application.

Comment: Im using visualstudio with aspx.net to deal with webservices, thats why i've used the tag c#

Comment: But you say you use Android Studio in your question?